# Why my drawings disappear after I release my left click?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

So I am trying to draw lines in OpenGL between the points where I click. The drawing is on the screen if I am pressing the left click, but it disappears if I release my left click:

```
struct Vector {
    float x, y;
    Vector(float x = 0, float y = 0) : x(x), y(y) {}

} last_mouse_pos;

void onInitialization() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); // A hatterszin beallitasa.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // A kepernyo torlese, az uj hatterszinnel.
}

void onDisplay() {
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

Vector convertToNdc(float x, float y) {
    Vector ret;
    ret.x = (x - kScreenWidth / 2) / (kScreenWidth / 2);
    ret.y = (kScreenHeight / 2 - y) / (kScreenHeight / 2);
    return ret;
}

int i = 0;

void onMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {

    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glutPostRedisplay(); 
    }
    else if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            i++;
            if (i == 1) last_mouse_pos = convertToNdc(x, y);
            if (i > 1) {
                Vector pos = convertToNdc(x, y);
                glBegin(GL_LINES);  
                glVertex2f(last_mouse_pos.x, last_mouse_pos.y);
                glVertex2f(pos.x, pos.y);
                glEnd();
                glutPostRedisplay();
                last_mouse_pos = pos; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I make 2 points, it draws the line if I am keep pressing the left click, if I release it, the screen gets black. If I click somewhere else, now I have 2 lines but only if I am pressing the left click. If I release, all of it gets black again.

Comment: You're probably getting a `WM_ERASE` message.

Comment: Your drawing only happens in the mouse down code.. Buffers in OpenGL are swapped (in your case: `glutSwapBuffers`).. you aren't drawing every frame so it gets wiped when the next frame renders.

Comment: If I swapped already... why it swaps back?

Comment: Don't draw in your input callbacks, latch some state & request a re-call of your display callback via `glutPostRedisplay()` and do the drawing there.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's quite a lot wrong with your approach here. In almost all cases, your draw function should be data driven *(i.e. data controls what is drawn, and nothing but data!)*. Something along these lines:

```cpp
// use this vector to store all of the point clicks
std::vector<Vector> points;

void onDisplay() {

  // now just render each vertex making up the lines
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  for(auto p : points)
    glVertex2f(p.x, p.y);
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Next up, you will need to track the state of the mouse, so with the aim of keeping this as simple as possible *(you may want to track the mouse position, and other button states as well, but this is a minimal example)*.

```cpp
bool leftHeld = false;
```

Next up your mouse function will now do the following:

1. When the left button is pressed, add a new vertex to the points array.
2. When left button is released, update the position of the last point in the array
3. When the right button is pressed (and the left button is not pressed), clear the array of points.

```cpp
void onMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  switch(button) {
  case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    {
      leftHeld = state == GLUT_DOWN;
      if(leftHeld)
      {
        points.push_back(convertToNdc(x, y)); // add new point
      }
      else
        points.back() = convertToNdc(x, y); // update last point
    }
    break;

  // on right click, empty the array
  // (but only if the left mouse button isn't currently pressed!)
  case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON: 
    if(!leftHeld && state == GLUT_DOWN)
      points.clear();
    break;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Finally, if you want to see the lines update as you click and drag on the screen, you'll need to register a mouse motion function to update the last point in the array

```cpp
// register with glutMotionFunc. 
// code updates last coordinate whilst mouse is moving, and
// the left button is held. 
void onMouseMove(int x, int y) {
  if(leftHeld)
  {
    points.back() = convertToNdc(x, y);
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```